# How to use an array in jQuery, the array which can be read in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

How can I use an array in the following codes in order to read data from array in the php?
Actually in loop I write something like this 
But I do know how I can do that above array in below codes

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-row").click(function() {
      //var name = $("#name").val();
      //var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
      //var email = $("#email").val();
      var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td> <input type='text' name='name'> </td><td> <input type='text' name='quantity'> </td><td> <input type='text' name='email'> </td></tr>";
      $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function() {
      $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Add Row">
  </form>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
</body>
```

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Not entirely clear how this relates to php.

Comment: It's also slightly strange that you have a `<form>` that consists of only a button.

Comment: And the connection to php is?

Comment: Could you please share your PHP code? 
Basically if you want to use PHP code in the "view/template" file you just need to iterate through array and for each row print the data. If you have just one result then you don't need foreach.   `<?php foreach ($array as $row): ?>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'] ?>" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'] ?>" /></td>
<?php endforeach ?>`

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(Array)` send it to your PHP server using Ajax or whatever, then in the PHP side use `json_decode($_POST['array'], true)`

Comment: ok, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use an AJAX request, which jQuery includes in their API: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can do something like this:

```js
// Make sure you send a JSON object
var some_data_for_the_backend = {
    "lorem": "ipsum",
    "abc": 123
}

$.ajax({
    // I add the timestamp at the end of the URL 
    // so we can avoid any kind of cache, but you can skip that part
    url: "path/to/script.php?t="+$.now(),
    type: "POST",
    data: some_data_for_the_backend,
}).done(function (response) {
    // Do something with your backend response if you want to, like:
    console.log(response);
});
```

Then in your `script.php` or whatever it's named like, you just need to get the `$_POST` data, like so:

```php
$lorem = $_POST["lorem"];
$abc = $_POST["abc"];

//Output: "ipsum"
echo $lorem;

//Output: "134"
echo $abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Fundamentally(!)* Javascript runs on the "client" computer ... your machine ... while PHP runs on the "server" computer.  These are two separate *computers.*

You must design your application so that the two sides communicate in some appropriate way, i.e. using AJAX.  For instance, each time your user inserts a new row into the table (and finishes filling it out), JavaScript code would have to detect this and make an AJAX call sending the new information to PHP.  Likewise for change and delete.

But ... you don't have to start blind here.  This very-familiar scenario is called "CRUD" = Create Read Update Delete.  There are already-built systems that do this, such as the venerable "Datatables" JavaScript library, and the corresponding PHP-side code needed to drive them is also readily available as downloadable PHP packages.  Therefore, step back for a few minutes from what you're doing and "do some Googling."  *"Do not do a thing already done."*

If you'd like to look at *source code* examples that don't rely on big JS libraries, surf over to https://github.com *(one of the world's best-known libraries of contributed software),* and search for *(say ...)* `php crud`.  You'll get over 9,000 results.  Just pick one and poke-around its source code.  Look at what they've done and how they did it.  *(And, if this isn't homework, feel free to steal some!)*